# Not able to change a date of my Picasa Web Albums album via Python API

Tags: python, api, gdata, picasa

I am not able to change a date of my *Picasa Web Albums* album via Python API. Spent many hours with that and I am hopeless now. Code:

```
# set values
remote_album.timestamp.text = str(get_published_as_timestamp())
remote_album.published.text = published + 'T04:01:01.000Z'

# test before
print remote_album.published
print remote_album.published.text
print remote_album.timestamp.text

# save it remotely
remote_album = picasa.Put(remote_album, remote_album.GetEditLink().href, converter=gdata.photos.AlbumEntryFromString)

# test after
print remote_album.published.text
print remote_album.timestamp.text

# :'-(
```

Output is:

```
<ns0:published xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">2010-12-24T04:01:01.000Z</ns0:published>
2010-12-24T04:01:01.000Z
1293148000
1970-01-15T23:12:28.000Z
1293148000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to change my album timestamp as follows:

```
album.timestamp = gdata.photos.Timestamp(
    text="%d000" % time.mktime((2010, 02, 03, 12, 00, 00, -1, -1, -1)))
updated_album = gd_client.Put(
    album, 
    album.GetEditLink().href, 
    converter=gdata.photos.AlbumEntryFromString)
```

Obviously my code is different from yours (and I have literally only just started with the gdata api today), but it shows how to make a new timestamp object and assign it to the album timestamp.

http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#ModifyAlbums

HTH